# C# Log4net in C++ Qt version

Tags: c#, c++, qt, logging

I'm working on Logging function in Qt on windows . I used Log4net in C# VS2010 before. Does anyone know any third party library doing the same way as Log4net?
Such as rolling file and logging level.

Comment: How about [log4cxx](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [QT 5.0 - Built in Logging?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305374/qt-5-0-built-in-logging)